# Prove that if $\dim(V)=2\dim(W)$ then $V=W \oplus W_1 = W \oplus W_2 = W_1 \oplus W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was given this question:

> There's a finite dimensional vector space $V$, and $W,W_1,W_2$ subspaces of $V$ that have this properties: $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{ 0 \}$ and $V=W+W_1=W+W_2$.
> Prove that if $\dim(V)=2\dim(W)$ then $V=W \oplus W_1 = W \oplus W_2 = W_1 \oplus W_2$.

I found in my book two sentences that I believe have to do with this proof:

1. If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ then $U$ is a finite dimensional subspace that exists $\dim(U) \le \dim(V)$ and $\dim(U) = \dim(V)$ exists if and only if $U=V$.
2. If $U$ and $W$ are two finite dimensional subspaces, and if $V=U+W$ then $V=U \oplus W$ if and only if $\dim(V) = \dim(U) + \dim (W)$.

I've been stuck on how to approach this, can I please get a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $W_1\subseteq V$ and $W_2\subseteq V$, $W_1+W_2\subseteq V$.
Since $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$, the sum above is a directe sum. So $\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)\le\dim V$.

$V=W+W_1$ implies $\dim(V)\le \dim(W)+\dim(W_1)$.

$V=W+W_2$ implies $\dim(V)\le \dim(W)+\dim(W_2)$.

Adding all inequalities above and cancelling out, we get
$$\dim V\le2\dim(W),$$
which is, in fact, an equality as given. Hence all inequalities above must be equalities.

Now you can try applying the second statement you found in your book.

Answer (score 1):

From Grassmann formula (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Grassmann%27s_Identity): $$2d=dim(V)=dim(W+W_1)=dim(W+W_2)=$$ $$=d+d_1-dim(W\cap W_1)=d+d_2-dim(W\cap W_2)\implies d_1,d_2\ge d.$$
But now, if we study $W_1+W_2$: $$ 2d=dim(V)\ge dim(W_1+W_2)=dim(W_1)+ dim(W_2)- dim(W_1\cap W_2)=$$ $$=dim(W_1)+ dim(W_2)=d_1+d_2\ge 2d.$$  We get the equality $d_1=d_2=d$ and  from the first inequality we get $dim(W\cap W_1)=dim(W\cap W_2)=0$, from here the thesis follows easily.